# Inline template expansion macro for Trac

Tags: macros, trac

IncludMacro for Trac wiki allows for inclusion of another wiki page (or other content) as is into the page that calls [[Include(PageName)]].

I am looking for a template expansion macro/mechanism that would allow me to have a template page that would contain, for example (this is trivial example just to illustrate):

```
= $(Title) =
This is a page with a title $(Title).

It is being maintained by $(Maintainer).
```

This could be included, with expansion, into a wiki page via a command like:

```
[[ExpandTemplate(CommonPageHeader,Title=Page Title,Maintainer=First Last)]]
```

which would result in all instances of "$(Title)" being replaced with "Page Title", same with $(Maintainer).

--- 2014-09-02 Edit ---

I am looking to deploy this in Trac 1.0.

More details of what ultimately I am looking to do (and notes on my research) can be found on http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/SearchForUltimateWikiTemplateMacro

Answer (score 1):

To me the magic of Trac is that you can implement something like this in fewer lines of code than it took you to describe it:

```py
import string
from trac.wiki import *
from trac.wiki.macros import WikiMacroBase


class ExpandTemplateMacro(WikiMacroBase):
    def expand_macro(self, formatter, name, content, args):
        args, kw = parse_args(content)
        return format_to_html(self.env, formatter.context, string.Template(WikiPage(self.env, args[0]).text).safe_substitute(kw))
```

I think this single-file plugin does what you describe in your question. Here's a bit more complete version (a slight variant of one I use myself):

```py
import string
from trac.core import TracError
from trac.wiki.macros import WikiMacroBase
from trac.wiki.formatter import format_to_html
from trac.wiki.api import parse_args
from trac.wiki.model import WikiPage

def resolve_wiki_page_name(wiki, pagename, referrer_resource):
    referrer = ''
    if referrer_resource and referrer_resource.realm == 'wiki':
        referrer = referrer_resource.id
    if pagename.startswith('/'):
        pagename = pagename.lstrip('/')
    elif pagename.startswith('./') or pagename.startswith('../') \
                                   or pagename in ('.', '..'):
        pagename = wiki._resolve_relative_name(pagename, referrer)
    else:
        pagename = wiki._resolve_scoped_name(pagename, referrer)
    return pagename

class ExpandTemplateMacro(WikiMacroBase):
    """Expands another wiki page with template parameters.

    The first argument is the page name of another wiki page.

    Example:
    {{{
        [[ExpandTemplate(CommonPageHeader,Title=Page Title,Maintainer=First Last)]]
    }}}
    where the CommonPageHeader template wiki page contains:
    {{{
        = $Title =
        This is a page with a title $Title.

        It is being maintained by $Maintainer.
    }}}
    """

    def expand_macro(self, formatter, name, content, args):
        args, kw = parse_args(content)
        wiki = formatter.wiki
        pagename = resolve_wiki_page_name(wiki, args[0], formatter.resource) if args else ''
        if not (pagename and wiki.has_page(pagename) and
                'WIKI_VIEW' in formatter.perm('wiki', pagename)):
            raise TracError('wiki page not found')
        page = WikiPage(self.env, pagename)
        expanded = string.Template(page.text).safe_substitute(kw) 
        return format_to_html(self.env, formatter.context, expanded)
```

---

(Another vaguely similar plugin is http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/BoilerplatePlugin. It's not quite what you want, but might still be interesting...)

Comment: Thank You. This is why I love Python, and I am just learning to appreciate Trac's implementation in it.You mentioned that you are already using something similar - is it a published plugin/macro, or something you're just using in your setup?

Comment: I have not got around to publish it before. The only differences are the added templating support, the context (included vs. including page) and I like to auto-insert an "Edit" link. Plus I have second variant that wraps it in a foldable section.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at [PageVariableMacro](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/PageVariableMacro) and [ParametrizedTemplatesPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/ParametrizedTemplatesPlugin). Both do not provide the complete solution, but implement parts of the requested functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. You mentioned two plugins, but both links point to the same one.  Which was the second?

Comment: Probably IncludeMacro? User have previously reported using them together, IIRC.

Comment: @MarcinAKomorowski Thank you for the request. I've just added the correct 2nd link.

Comment: @RjOllos, I have looked at IncludeMacro - it provides the 'include content of another page' part, but is missing 1) rendering in the context of the page issuing `[[Include(...)]]`, and 2) passing values to be filled out in the template.

Comment: @hasienda, thanks for the update to your answer.  The ParameterizedTemplatePlugin is interesting in itself and I may also use it, but it is used to generate a new static page, instead of dynamically expanding a template on rendering of a wiki page.

Comment: If you do not feel up to the task of merging and extending Trac plugin functionality yourself, consider requesting a hack (--> http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/RequestaHack) and ask at for support at our 'trac-users' mailing-list (--> http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/MailingList).

Answer (score 0):

[ParameterizedIncludeMacro](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/ParameterizedIncludeMacro) was published to trac-hacks.org in the past day or so.

Comment: Thank you for posting this.  One improvement to your macro I would suggest is allowing format like this: `[[ParameterizedInclude(PageName,ARG_NAME1=Arg Value,ARG_NAME2=Arg value 2,…)]]`.  This allows templates to have `{{ARG_NAME2}}` which makes them more readable.

Comment: Question: does your macro will render the content of the template page in the context of the template page, or the page where the template is being called?  This is important if the template calls macros to, for example, generate a table of contents.

Comment: It's not my macro, I just noticed that it had been published to trac-hacks.org. In regard to the first question, you could open a ticket for the plugin. For the second question, I suggest just doing some testing.